# When running Prometheus, all my endpoints start returning 404

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, prometheus

I have SpringBoot app that works just fine, my endpoints return proper responses when I hit my API endpoints using Postman.

Same with my Actuators.  They are working fine.

I also added spring dependencies `micrometer-core` and `micrometer-registry-prometheus` which added to my Actuators new path `/prometheus'.  This path also works just fine and returns metrics.

Since I wanted to see the graphing, I downloaded standalone Prometheus app (so no docker image) from official site (zip file) and unziped it.

Inside, there is prometheus.exe and prometheus.yaml file.

Even without modifying this yaml file at all, as soon as I double click on prometheus.exe to start it (which starts it properly), all of my endpoints stop returning 200 OK and start returning 404 Not Found responses.

Then I modified it to add my job name and path like

```
-job_name: 'spring-actuators'
 metric_path: '/myappname/actuator/prometheus'
 scrape_interval: 5s
 static_configs:
 - targets: ['localhost:9090']
```

even with this change to now scrape metrics from 'myappname', I still get 404 responses as soon as I start prometheus every time I try to send request to my API using Postman.

I notice that postman.exe console also shows error right after server is ready for requests:

```
level=info ts=2021-06-02T15:42:03.421Z caller=main.go:775 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
level=error ts=2021-06-02T15:42:10.374Z caller=db.go:780 component=tsdb msg="compaction failed" err="compact head: persist head block: rename block dir: rename data\\01F76P79CQDPFVGZS5XNTDTK4P.tmp-for-creation data\\01F76P79CQDPFVGZS5XNTDTK4P: Access is denied."
```

Comment: When you say "all my endpoints", you mean literally ALL of them? Even those you exposed by using `@RequestMapping` / `@GetMapping`, etc + the actuator ones? Or only the actuator endpoints?

Comment: I mean all.  My Controllers are annotated with RequestMapping, my endpoints with GetMapiing, PostMapping....  Also, all actuator endpoints including /prometheus endpoint are returning 404 once I run prometheus; otherwise, they all work just fine.

Comment: @Felipe I changed port in my SpringBoot app and I no longer get 404 although I still keep getting the error above.  Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it please.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is exposing endpoints on the same port of Prometheus `9090`. Change your spring boot application to expose the endpoint at `8080` or any other port except `9090`. Then scrape your app at that port.

```
-job_name: 'spring-actuators'
 metric_path: '/myappname/actuator/prometheus'
 scrape_interval: 5s
 static_configs:
 - targets: ['localhost:8080']
```